# What's expecting a function in this clojure code?

Tags: clojure

going through the exercises in the [fp-oo](https://leanpub.com/fp-oo) book and i'm having trouble with an early exercise to add squares.  Here's my code:

```
 (defn square [n]
   (* n n))

 (defn add-squares [l]
   (cond
     (nil? l) 0
     :else (+ (square (first (l))) (add-squares (rest (l))))))
```

This example:

```
(add-squares '(2 2 2 2))
```

should return

```
16
```

but fails with this exception:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/add-squares (NO_SOURCE_FILE:4)
```

which i guess means i'm trying to pass a function somewhere instead of a list which was expected.  Can someone tell me which part of the code is the culprit?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
(first (l))
```

This means that you are calling l as a function.

You should use:

```
(first l)
```

And of course, the same thing for (rest (l))

Comment: thanks, removing those parentheses around the l in the call to first and rest did it.